# How does reselect createStructuredSelector work in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux, reselect

I’m trying to understand how the reselect method `createStructuredSelector` works in Typescript. I see this pattern a lot:

```
export interface SomeProps {
   readonly property1: string;
   readonly property2: boolean;
   readonly property3: number;
}

export interface SomeOwnProps {
   readonly property3: number;
}

export const someSelector = createStructuredSelector<
    SomeState,
    SomeOwnProps,
    SomeProps
>({
   property1: property1Selector,
   property2: property2Selector,
   property3: (_, props) => props.property3
});
```

I don’t understand the purpose of the types inside of the angle brackets. I think `SomeState` is the Redux store state, `SomeOwnProps` are the props that were passed in by the parent component, and `SomeProps` are all the props that this component uses. But what is the difference between `SomeOwnProps` and `SomeProps`, and why do you need both? How come you can’t just use `SomeProps` since it also contains the properties defined in `SomeOwnProps`? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`createStructuredSelector` comes in two variants — one takes your component's own props, the second doesn't. If your desired selection does not depend on props, it's easier to go with the latter.

Consider this slightly contrived example:

```
/**
 * Data source (Redux store or a single reducer).
 */
interface State {
  readonly property1: string;
  readonly property2: boolean;
  readonly property3: number;
}

/**
 * Your component's OwnProps.
 */
interface OwnProps {
  index: 1 | 2 | 3;
}

/**
 * The interface you want to create.
 */
interface DesiredSelection {
  someString: string;
  someNumber: number;
};
```

When your selection *does not* depend on props:

```
const mySelector = createStructuredSelector<State, DesiredSelection>({
  someString: state => state.property1,
  someNumber: state => state.property3
});
```

When your selection *does* depend on props:

```
const mySelectorBasedOnProps = createStructuredSelector<State, OwnProps, DesiredSelection>({
  someString: state => state.property1,
  someNumber: (state, props) =>
    (props.index === 1)
      ? 1
      : state.property3
});
```

The distinction between `OwnProps` and `DesiredSelection` is needed because the former can influence the latter. It's a common pattern to select data from different parts of your Redux store based on the props your component has received from its parent.

Somewhat more realistic example:

```
interface State {
  translations: {
    au: 'Hello, mate!',
    uk: 'Welcome, old chap!'
  }
}

interface OwnProps {
  country: 'au' | 'uk';
}

interface ConnectedProps {
  message: string
};

/**
 * These are all props your component will receive.
 */
type Props = OwnProps & ConnectedProps;

const getMessage = createStructuredSelector<State, OwnProps, ConnectedProps>({
  message: (state, props) => state.translations[props.country]
});
```